# Get the element with the highest value in a tuple in a dictionary

Tags: python

What is the best way to get an element with the highest dictionary value in list of tuple? I tried lambda but didn't work out and tried indexing too but didn't work out either. This is my code:

```
def winning_card(cards, trump=None):
  shortlist = []
  if trump is not None:
    for rank,suit in cards:
      if suit == suit[0]:
        shortlist.append(rank,suit)
        winning_card = max(shortlist)
    return winning_card
  else:
    for rank,suit in cards:
      if suit == trump:
        shortlist.append(rank,suit)
        winning_card = max(shortlist)
  return winning_card
```

I'm trying to solve this:

Playing cards are represented as tuples of (rank,suit). The winner of the trick is determined by the following rules:

1. If one or more cards of the trump suit have been played to the trick, the trick is won by the highest ranking trump card, regardless of the other cards played.
2. If no trump cards have been played to the trick, the trick is won by the highest card of the suit of the 5irst card played to the trick. Cards of any other suits, regardless of their rank, are powerless to win that trick.
3. Ace is the highest card in each suit.

[image]

Comment: Please include an example. Include the output that your code produces, the desired output, and mention how they differ if it's not obvious. What is "5irst"? And what is "cardproblems.py"? If you could just give a concise outline of the proper order of the cards, that would be best for anyone reading the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should do it.  Handling the rules around the suit is simple as long as you can map each suit of interest to a value that will sort correctly relative to the others -- namely, the trump (if any) is highest, followed by the suit of the initial card.  Special-casing `trump is None` isn't necessary as long as none of the `cards` will have a `suit` of `None`.

```
def winning_card(cards, trump=None):
    suit_score = {
        trump: 2,
        cards[0][1]: 1,
    }
    rank_score = {
        'two': 2,
        'three': 3,
        'four': 4,
        # etc
        'king': 13,
        'ace': 14,
    }
    return max(cards, key=lambda card: (
        suit_score.get(card[1], 0), rank_score[card[0]]
    ))
```